# JWT tokens with Apache HTTP server

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, jwt

We are utilizing Apache HTTP server as a gateway in AWS for APIs and front-end web code in S3 buckets.  We currently use mod_auth_mellon for authentication and pass user information in headers back to our API's when a client successfully authenticates.

We are looking to switch to AWS Cognito for authentication utilizing JWT.

I have been experimenting with mod_authz_jwt (https://github.com/AnthonyDeroche/mod_authnz_jwt).  On it's own, I can utilize JWT to grant access to protected URI's.  When I attempt to utilize it with Cognito, I am running into errors.

Steps used to recreate:
I harvest jwks.json for our specific user pool.
/.well-known/jwks.json
I pull the one public key from it that our JWT tokens are signed with.
I run that public key through the following process:
Convert it to pem:  jwk-to-pem
Trim out all unnecessary info from pem:
openssl rsa -inform pem -in FILEPATH.pem -pubin -pubout -RSAPublicKey_in

When I put the JWT token I have and the fully processed pem into the debugger on jwt.io, the signature validates correctly.  However, when I throw them into Apache utilizing mod_authz_jwt, I get an invalid token and/or invalid signature error.

Has anyone been able to make this work or have any alternative solutions to my problem?

Comment: An alternative would be: https://github.com/pingidentity/mod_auth_openidc with it's OAuth 2.0 RS functionality.